# Is there an equivalent shortcut in RStudio of the Ctrl + D command in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rstudio

The Command + D or Ctrl + D (in Windows) keybinding in VS Code allows you to add the next occurrence of a selected portion of code to your current selection.

Is there an equivalent in RStudio?

Comment: maybe you can find something here, => https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-the-RStudio-IDE

Comment: Sorry, no... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent shortcut, but you can get cursors on all occurrences by pressing Cmd/Ctrl F, then selecting "All" matches:

[image: all matches]

Comment: Many thanks, this is close enough for me!

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for the `Find and Add Next` command that is available in the RStudio Keyboard Shortcuts Menu.

For selecting single words it works without initial selection as well.
Simply place your cursor somewhere on the current word, press `Cmd+D` (or whatever keybinding you have assigned) and it first selects the current word and then consecutively adds the next word occurence to the selection.

To my knowledge there is currently no way to skip an occurrence and continue the same selection afterwards nor to go backwards and consecutively add previous occurences to the selection whereas both of these are possible in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I'd say this is the answer that most closely mimics the Ctrl+D functionality of VSCode

Comment: this is incredible! i replaced delete with find and add next, and it works very well.